# different Integration test arquilian

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spock, jboss-arquillian

.

Pls. Help me to identify difference between arqulian testing  and spock testing plugin or others . . How they are different from each other. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arquillian: testing inside the container which means that  a deployable archive (jar, war or ear) is created automatically, it is deployed in the container (tomcat, jboss, glassfish etc) and then run tests in it. So you "write real tests", you don't need to mock anything and you can test your application end-to-end (if needed).
Spock: used for unit testing and has its own mock mechanisms. It has a lot of similarities with jUnit or TestNG. Difference is that you must write your tests in Groovy (not in Java).

Comment: It should be noted that the majority of java code you would write is valid Groovy. Groovy is more like Java+1 than a separate language

Comment: Thanks for help. But still a question. .we used to write integration test cases. How arquilian is different from existing integration tests.

Comment: how did you use to write your integration tests?

Comment: I understood by implementing it. Thanks All fpr participation :)

Comment: Alex::  initially i was working on grails. So it provides its own integration test layers API's throught which i can write and execute my applications test case